# StackOverflow not recognizing C++ on filter

Tags: support, stack-overflow, search

I was filtering questions so that I can see C++ and C# questions, I thought it's better to filter `[C++]` `[or]` `[C#]`.

First time I typed `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b% c%23` for C++ and C#
[image]

Second time I typed `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b+or+c%23` for C++ or C#

[image]

Why `[C]`? when I add or to the filter it confuses `C++` with `C`

Am I missing something? Or should this be reported? If someone has any information please help me I'm dazed

Comment: Belongs on Meta ?

Comment: Just so you know `[c++] [or] [c#]` in the search bar works as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mixing `+` encodings here, the proper URL for the style you have would be:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20or%20c%23

The alternative, if in doubt, is to have any `xxxx+` tag at the end (which gets special love to handle all the cases we reasonably can), like this:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23 or c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c#%20or%20c++)
(note the hash still needs encoding, there's no way around that one)